# Map through nested object with variable number of fields?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-component, map-function

```json
{
    "pagesections": [
        {
            "title": "Executive Board",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "title": "Co-Founders/Co-Presidents",
                    "team": [
                        {
                            "name": "Emily ZhouWang",
                            "designation": "Co-Founder",
                            "image": "../images/sample_image.jpg",
                            "clg": "Junior at UC Berkeley",
                            "linkedin": "",
                            "description": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Kathleen Kong",
                            "designation": "Co-Founder",
                            "image": "../images/sample_image.jpg",
                            "clg": "Junior at UC Berkeley",
                            "linkedin": "",
                            "description": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Directors",
                    "team": [
                        {
                            "name": "Emily ZhouWang",
                            "designation": "Co-Founder",
                            "image": "../images/sample_image.jpg",
                            "clg": "Junior at UC Berkeley",
                            "linkedin": "",
                            "description": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Kathleen Kong",
                            "designation": "Co-Founder",
                            "image": "../images/sample_image.jpg",
                            "clg": "Junior at UC Berkeley",
                            "linkedin": "","
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Co-Founders/Co-Presidents",
                    "team": [
                        {
                            "name": "Emily ZhouWang",
                            "designation": "Co-Founder",
                            "image": "../images/sample_image.jpg",
                            "clg": "Junior at UC Berkeley",
                            "linkedin": "",
                            "description": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Kathleen Kong",
                            "designation": "Co-Founder",
                            "image": "../images/sample_image.jpg",
                            "clg": "Junior at UC Berkeley",
                            "linkedin": "",
                            "description": ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Tech Team"
        },
        {
            "title": "Ambassadors"
        }
    ],
}
```

This is how my JSON file looks like. I'm trying to import and use it in following React component. There are three returns. One corresponds to pagesections, another to sections and last one to team. But there seems to be an error. I've tried using this.sections.map() and this.team.map() but it doesn't seem to work either. 'team' and 'sections' are not recognized in that case but here they are recognized but the map function does not seem to work.

```js
{data.pagesections.map((e)=>{  //error is pointed at this line and
                return (
                    <Grid container direction="column" className={classes.root}>      
                        <Grid item className={classes.head1} key={e}>  *//this line
                            <Team_Section title={e.title}/>
                        </Grid>
            
                        {e.sections.map((t)=> {
                            return (
                                <>
                                <Grid item key={t}>
                                    <Section_Head title={t.title}/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item container>
                                    <Grid item xs={1} sm={1} md={2}/>
                                    <Grid container spacing={4} justify="center" item xs={10} sm={10} md={8} align="center">
                                    {t.team.map((g)=>{
                                        return (
                                            <Grid item xs={6} key={g}>
                                                <MediaCard 
                                                    name={g.name}
                                                    designation={g.designation}
                                                    image={g.image}
                                                    clg={g.clg}
                                                    linkedin={g.linkedin}
                                                    description={g.description}/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item xs={1} sm={1} md={2}/>
                                </Grid>
                                </>
                            );
                        })}
                    </Grid>
                );
            })}
```

> **Error**: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use optional chaining so that you only map through objects that contain arrays and ignore the ones that don't

```
import data from "./data.json";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.pagesections.map((r) => (
        <>
          <div>{r.title}</div>
          {r.sections?.map((i) => {
            return (
              <>
                {i.team?.map((s) => {
                  return <div>{s.name}</div>;
                })}
              </>
            );
          })}
        </>
      ))}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

attached is a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-mclean-wp3cb?file=/src/App.js:0-536

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Could you also provide a way to access images in a different folder if I had to specify it in JSON file and use in React component.

Answer (score 1):

You map all elements of the array. There are two elements that have not nested arrays to map.

```js
{
   "title": "Tech Team"
},
{
   "title": "Ambassadors"
}
```

When you try to map `e.sections.map` there are no `sections`, so you are trying to map undefined and get the error.

You should either filter array to exclude such objects or add a check that array you want to map exists.

`e.sections && e.sections.map((t) => {...})`
`t.team && t.team.map((g) => {...})`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear here. You trying to iterate over `undefined`, cause your `data.pagesections` is not defined (array doesn't contain `pagesections` or is not assigned yet).

Try this:

`data && data.pagesections && data.pagesections.map(e => {...})`

or if you are using typescript (or newest javascript):

`data?.pagesections?.map(e => {...})`

also repeat same with inner `map` function.

Comment: Optional chaining is a general JS feature.  You don't need Typsescript to use it.

Comment: You are right, forgot that optional chaining is also already in JS.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.